# Is it possible to read the header of an archived WAL segment?

Tags: postgresql, wal

I would like to read the PostgreSQL archived WAL segment header to get some information to the content of the file. In compare, under MS SQL I can run 
a `restore headeronly ...` command and get information about each backup file, including transaction log backup files. I will get the firstLSN and the lastLSN and a lot of other useful information.

Is there some similar possibility in PostgreSQL?

This is a general question.

En example of the similar possibility in MS SQL:

```
restore headeronly from disk = 'E:\archived_logs\prd_tr_log_20190913100000-.bak';
go
```

Result set with the FirstLSN, LastLSN and other information.

Comment: Not a SQL command, but maybe you are looking for [pg_waldump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgwaldump.html)

Comment: Thank you. Looks very interesting. I don't really need an SQL command, just any possibility. Do you know, where I can find some examples how to use the application ?

Comment: Thank you. I just worked by "try and error" and pg_waldump is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't store a whole lot of information in the header.  From the source code:

```
typedef struct XLogLongPageHeaderData
{
    XLogPageHeaderData std;     /* standard header fields */
    uint64      xlp_sysid;      /* system identifier from pg_control */
    uint32      xlp_seg_size;   /* just as a cross-check */
    uint32      xlp_xlog_blcksz;    /* just as a cross-check */
} XLogLongPageHeaderData;
```

So the sysid could be used to make sure that the WAL file belongs to the system you think it does (matches pg_control), but there is nothing else which is meaningful to the end user.

You can probably use pg_waldump to get the first and last LSN (although those are more or less implied by the name of the file itself, so this of dubious value), but you can't just get those from the header because they are not present in the header.